# Разместить react-sidebar по скролу

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Компонент [react-sidebar](https://github.com/balloob/react-sidebar#styles) позволяет сделать сайтбар размером с высоту экрана. Мне нужно на сайте с прокруткой, чтоб сайтбар выходил не сверху, а смещенный на высоту скрола. Если я делаю marginTop, то он просто обрезается и не смещается.

```
<Sidebar
        styles={{
          sidebar: {
            background: "white",
            height: "2000px",
            zIndex: 20,
            maxWidth: "683px",
            backgroundColor: "#edf2f9",
            boxShadow: "-20px 0 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)"
          }

        }}
      />
```

[image]

Так выглядит мой сайтбар, он отображается как надо и он ровно на высоту экрана(если прокрутить чуть ниже, он там заканчивается). Мне нужно, если я кликну по элементу не в навбаре или хэдаре, а по какому-то ниже стоящему, чтоб сайт бар так же самого отрисовался на том скроле, где я нахожусь в данный момент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего не понятно, но используете `position: fixed` и `top: 0`

Это позволит элементу располагаться относительно окна игнорируя скролл ( то есть он всегда будет виден в окне, если вы проставите нужные координаты )

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
let isShown = false;

container.onclick = function () {
   isShown ?
       sidebar.style.display = 'none' :
       sidebar.style.display = 'block';
   isShown = !isShown
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 5000px;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #333;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>Кликните для появления sidebar</div>
<div class='sidebar'></div>
```

Конкретно в вашем случае попробуйте передавать в компонент стили

```
root: {
    position: 'fixed',
}
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно. Мне надо, чтоб когда я прокрутил скрол, то сайт бар был бы на высоту отображаемого сейчас экрана, а не на всю высоту страницы вообще

Comment: @АлександрМангир с чего вы взяли что он на всю высоту страницы? Вы посмотрите через деббагер высоту у `sidebara` ( 199px  у меня в неразвернутом примере ). Высота будет считаться относительно экрана, а не страницы

Comment: а как это можно сделать с помощью https://github.com/balloob/react-sidebar#styles ?

Comment: @АлександрМангир обновил